# How to define a pattern in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this 4 pages:

- project/create.xhtml
- project/load.xhtml
- project/edit.xhtml
- project/details.xhtml

This is the spring security config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="//pages/project/[ec].*/"     access="hasRole('PROJECT_WRITE')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/project/load**" access="hasRole('PROJECT_READ')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/project/detail**" access="hasRole('PROJECT_READ')"/>
</security:http>
```

I need to filter pages when its starts with e (for edit) and c (for create) but i don't know.
This is the correct regex **//pages/project/[ec].*/** but don't work.

is it possible?

Load an detail page work fine but is a easy url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing slash at the end of the regex.  You can also remove one of the slashes at the beginning.  Try this:

`/pages/project/[ec].*`